# Approximated of $f:D \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f:D \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is continuous, it can be approximated by polynomials? Why?

$D = {z\in \mathbb{C}:|z-z_o|<r}$

polynomials in one complex variable with complex coefficients

Comment: What is $D$ in this problem? And I think the word is “approximated”.

Comment: Is $D$ the open (or closed) unit disk? By polynomials, do you mean polynomials in one complex variable $P(z)=a_0+a_1 z+\cdots+a_nz^n$?

Comment: Thank you until now and sorry for bad english

Comment: If polynomials in both $z$ and $\overline{z}$, or equivalently, polynomials in $x$ and $y$, where $x$ and $y$ are the real resp.imaginary part, then: Weierstraß approximation theorem. If only polynomials in $z$, then you can't (locally) uniformly approximate arbitrary continuous functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no if you only consider complex polynomials
$$P(z)=a_0+a_1 z+\cdots+a_nz^n$$
and yes if you consider polynomials in two variables ($z=x+iy$)
$$P(z)=\sum_{k,l\leq N}a_{k,l}x^ky^l.$$
The second case is an easy application of the Stone Weierstrass density theorem. To see why an arbitrary continuous map may not be approximated by standard complex polynomials, you could use the fact that a uniform limit of holomorphic functions is holomorphic, or notice that, say for $\rho=\frac12r$, and for any polynomial $P$,
$$\int_{|z|=\rho}P(z)\,dz=0$$
If $f$ is a uniform limit of polynomials $P_n$ then one would have to have
$$\int_{|z|=\rho}f(z)\,dz=0$$